# Is there a model to explain the formation of a solid?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

This is a rather simple question but I haven't found an answer here, I hope it's not a duplicate.

Is there a model to explain the formation of a solid? In other words, Is there a way to start a model with free particles, then make them interact with eath other and get an equilibrium state where they are fixed in a lattice? And if so, does it include the posibility of phase transition from solid to liquid?

Comment: This question is too broad - can you pose a more specific problem? A couple of thoughts though: there are many theoretical models that describe phase nucleation and transitions, such as [CNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_nucleation_theory), although many systems proceed via non-classical mechanisms. And phase nucleation and transitions can be directly simulated (in some instances) using methods such as [molecular dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics).

Comment: Indeed it is too broad. And, the literature is full of papers doing just what is asked in a wide variety of materials systems.

Comment: Hello! thanks for the comment. I was just wondering if a mathematical model could give a lattice as the equilibrium solution of  interacting moving particles, how could I make it more specific? I really don't know much about the subject. thanks again!

Comment: @JonCuster could you cite one? I'd really like to read them

Comment: You could start with 'Atomistic to continuum modeling of solidification microstructures', Alain Karma and Damien Tourret, Current Opintion in Solid State and Materials Science, 20(1) 25-36 (2016). Actually, the entire issue is modeling of solidification...

Comment: "I was just wondering if a mathematical model could give a lattice as the equilibrium solution of interacting moving particles". If you can identify suitable order parameters for the material you're interested in then you could construct a free energy map and show that a particular phase minimises it. See, for example, simulation studies employing metadynamics.